# How to specify a relative date in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I already know how to, for instance, get tomorrow's date in a query in SQL; either use `ADDDATE(CURDATE(),1)` or `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAYS)` (or something like that).

But how would I get a date that is a bit more eccentric, for example the 10th of next month?

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do would be to handle that in your application before sending the request to the SQL server. PHP's `strtotime(...)` can handle weird formats like that, but I don't know of any easy way in SQL.

Comment: No can do. This is done in a .sql file. I need pure SQL logic.

Comment: Did you literally want to find the 10th of next month? My assumption was you wanted some basic natural language processing, which is pretty much not doable in MySQL.

Comment: You can probably do anything you can think of in a multi-line batch or stored procedure. @zerkms has given you a one-liner for the exact case you raise, but is there a general case you want to implement?

Comment: @Alexander Sagen yes I wanted to find the 10th of next month, not parse a string which says the 10th of next month; sorry, I took out the quotes to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD**

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()) + IF(MONTH(NOW()) = 12, 1, 0), '-', IF(MONTH(NOW()) = 12, 0, MONTH(NOW())) + 1, '-', 10), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

yes, it looks weird, but it solves "now is december" issue ;-)

Comment: Won't this break for December? And he was probably looking for a more general solution.

Comment: I'm not sure, i have no mysql to check right now. It would be great if somebody checks it.

Comment: `mysql> select STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', 13, '-', 10), '%Y-%m-%d');` returns NULL. 12 as month works.

Comment: You will need to feed a format to Str_to_date like this: Select Str_to_Date(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW())+1, '-', 10), '%Y-%m-%d') - apart from this the query will work except for December, but I guess zerkms just wanted to show how this kind of calculation *could* be done.

Comment: @faxi05, yes, I forgot about second argument... Fixed, as well as "december issue"

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing in MySQL, this has to be done before DB. At least with the flexibility you suggest when wanting generally "more eccentric".

Perhaps not a good idea to have that kind of logic in a query anyways? Depending on your case ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start by quoting a comment from above, and saying I totally agree with it:

Did you literally want to find the 10th of next month? My assumption was you wanted some basic natural language processing, which is pretty much not doable in MySQL. – Alexander Sagen 6 hours ago

However, if you're absolutly, totally, desperate, then you could look at writing your own function to do this. You'd have to work out first exactly what sort of inputs you're going to send (i.e are you literally going to pass a single string value such as "10th of next month"), or can this be represented as day,month , so 10,+1 in the example. If it's the latter, it makes things a lot easier. Otherwise, you're looking at evaluating the text of the input and making decisions about what to do. Big IF statements, basically. It's doable - but it isn't what SQL was made for.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I did simply want to get the date equivalent to (year)/(month+1)/10 , not parse a string. Thanks for covering all the bases though! I removed quotes to maybe make the question more clear.

Comment: Ah, it's easy then! You should be able to do it with DATEADD. You may still need to do it in a function - but it should be a case of adding the month, removing the same number of days as there are today, then adding as many days as you want to find. So for 1,10 (10th of next month)

1) add 1 for the month to today = 29-10-2010,   
2) remove (days in today=29) = 01-10-2010,  
3) add 10 = 10-10-2010

Answer (score 0):

For complex date logic you might want to consider pre-generating a date table and selecting from it. Having the appropriate columns will make selection with where clauses easier. Its a common and almost required technique for data warehouses. Something like this perhaps:

http://www.ipcdesigns.com/dim_date/

Then you can do (if I understood his schema correctly):

`SELECT
     full_date 
FROM date_table 
WHERE date_table.day_num_of_month = 10 AND 
      date_table.month_num_overall = (SELECT month_num_overall+1 FROM date_table WHERE full_date = NOW())`